# Converting n-dimensional array quoted inside string to n-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy, types

I have a string that contains an n-dimensional array.

```
a = '[[1,2],[3,4]]'
```

I want the output to be:

```
b = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

I have tried `np.array(a)` but it not working.
Can I get a one-line solution for it?
Thank you

Comment: Try `from ast import literal_eval   b = literal_eval(a)`

Comment: `b = json.loads(a)`